# Erro ao tentar obter uma lista de calendários com Calendar API da Google

Tags: android-studio, google, google-calendar, google-api

Estou tentando obter uma lista de calendários utilizando o Calendar API da google. A autenticação com o google funciona perfeitamente, porém, ao solicitar a lista de calendários eu recebo um erro de código 401. O que pode estar fazendo a minha chamada estar retornando esse erro?

```
Call<JsonObject> call = RetrofitClient.googleService().listCalendars(
                    token, getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key));

@GET("calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList")
Call<JsonObject> listCalendars(
        @Header("Authorization") String token,
        @Query("key") String key);
```

Minha instancia do Retrofit:

```
 public static Retrofit getInstanceGoogle(){
    if(retrofitGoogle == null) {
        return retrofitGoogle = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()))
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .connectTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofitGoogle;
}
```

O erro que é retornado:

> {
> "error": {
> "code": 401,
> "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Login Required.",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "required",
> "location": "Authorization",
> "locationType": "header"
> }
> ],
> "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
> }
> }

Tela de autenticação:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

SignInButton signInButton;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 930;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);

    signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Scope scope1 = new Scope(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(Fitness.SCOPE_ACTIVITY_READ, scope1)
            .requestIdToken(CLIENT_ID)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

     mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
    }
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setUserEmail(account.getEmail());
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: O código de resposta de status de erro do cliente [HTTP 401 Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401)  indica que a solicitação não foi aplicada porque não possui credenciais de autenticação válidas para o recurso de destino.

Comment: Eu solicito a permissão CALENDAR quando o usuário faz o login, vou tentar adicionar também a CALENDAR_READONLY e ver se funciona